# IAP invalid product IDs : SandBox testing

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

I already saw similar questions on StackOverflow with invalid product IDs but my case is different. We already have an app with IAP that we had to remove from sale. Now my problem is when I added a new version (not uploaded yet) and in-app purchases, Apple marks all the product IDs I supplied on SKProductRequest invalid. I also tried to supply the old product IDs for version 1 but those were marked invalid too.

Does anyone experience the same problem or at least had the same scenario and was able to get through? Thanks in advance!

--- UPDATE ---

I tried enabling the app again for just one Country but it didn't help at all. I was also able to make IAP work using a new test app with no problem (everything works instantly!)

Comment: Have you deleted the existing app from App store?

Comment: Nope, I just removed the app from from sale and added a new version (which I have not uploaded yet). App still exists in iTunes Connect and I'm using the same Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Nevermind, it was a silly mistake! I figured out it was a mismatched bundle ID, I'm pretty sure I triple check before...duh :|